# grab source image with xPath and Ruby

Tags: ruby, xpath

I want grab the source of this image

```
<td class="E6AEBFB-Zc-a E6AEBFB-Zc-s E6AEBFB-Zc-d"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-338"><a aria-label="Application 1231233" href="#AppDashboardPlace:p=tmp.13910559381666913670.1525434997761&amp;appid=4973853232983868726" data-column="TITLE"><img src="gwt/placeholder_icon_24.png" role="presentation"><div> <div>1231233</div> <div></div> </div> </a></div></td>
```

I have tried

```
  puts  tr.xpath("./td[1]//a[img]").text
  puts  tr.xpath("./td[1]//a[img]/@href").extract
```

but it's returns me nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked: `doc.xpath('/td[1]//a/img/@src').to_s`. I suspect `doc.xpath('/td[1]//a/img')[:src]` would work too.

Comment: I forgot to use `at_xpath`. Use that if you only want to return one element.